# Converting Zeep Objects to DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, zeep

long time listener, first time caller.

I've been learning Python and have hit a bit of a wall as I try to make use of the data I'm getting back from some work systems.

I am getting results back from a request to Five9 (call center software) sent with the `AdminWebService.GetStatistics()` method in this module: https://pypi.org/project/five9/

I can pull back the various responses and print them, but I'm a bit new to the game to understand what exactly is tripping me up.

After some extensive searching over the past couple days, I've tried to follow directions on:

Passing the output through `json.load`, `json.loads` and `json.loads(json.dumps(` before creating the DataFrame using `from_dict`

- this resulted in a lot of errors that I didn't fully document. It would fail to read the full output, but I was able to get it to `loads()` the output of just the `.rows` section. This almost worked, but when I'd try to pull it in as a DataFrame, I'd end up with `1 row and 114 columns`, for example.

Passing the `response.rows` element as the data to create the frame, and using `headers=response.columns` to specify the column names

- lots of failures due to lack of 2d inputs mostly.

Using the pandas.read_json() function

- I was able to create a dataframe, but it would be 1 row long. Depending on how i jiggered the inputs, it would sometimes be one row and one column called '[values]' or it would be one long row of every value in the response.

Using the zeep.helper serialize_object function

- seemed to yield promising results, but when I attempt to use the output to create a DataFrame, I receive the following error: `Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.`

Referring to the specific values within the dicts to manually build the frame.

- I seem to be able to use some form of response.rows[n]['values']['data'] syntax to get at the actual stuff inside each row, convert it to a string and split by commas before adding it as a sublist to a larger list to use as a dataframe, but it feels incredibly inefficient to loop through every row and process it multiple times.

Basically, I've found a few ways that work that involve converting the output to a string and then heavily formatting, replacing and parsing it with custom functions, but I *know* there's a more elegant solution that I just can't seem to work out. At this point, I'm fairly sure that I have used the required functions in my quest to understand this, but that I haven't used them properly in the right order. Any help turning this into a df would be much appreciated.

A sample response is here. All responses from this server are nested this way, **I just want to create a dataframe from the columns and rows**:

```
{
'columns': {
    'values': {
        'data': [
            'Campaign Name',
            'Current Action',
            'Mode',
            'Priority',
            'Profile',
            'Ratio',
            'State',
            'State Since',
            'Type'
        ]
    }
},
'rows': [
    {
        'values': {
            'data': [
                'Billing Inbound',
                None,
                'Advanced Mode',
                None,
                'KitchensInc-Main',
                None,
                'Stopping',
                '2020-04-01 17:17:51',
                'Inbound'
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        'values': {
            'data': [
                'HDWR-Support-Tier2-English',
                None,
                'Advanced Mode',
                None,
                'KitchensInc-Main',
                None,
                'Running',
                '2020-03-18 03:06:50',
                'Inbound'
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        'values': {
            'data': [
                'HDWRSupportTier2-French',
                None,
                'Advanced Mode',
                None,
                'KitchensInc-Main',
                None,
                'Running',
                '2020-03-18 03:06:51',
                'Inbound'
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        'values': {
            'data': [
                'Country1 Inbound',
                None,
                'Advanced Mode',
                None,
                'KitchensInc-Main',
                None,
                'Running',
                '2020-03-18 03:06:52',
                'Inbound'
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        'values': {
            'data': [
                'PromptManagement',
                None,
                'Basic Mode',
                None,
                None,
                None,
                'Running',
                '2020-03-18 03:06:53',
                'Inbound'
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        'values': {
            'data': [
                'Country9 Inbound',
                None,
                'Advanced Mode',
                None,
                'KitchensInc-Main',
                None,
                'Running',
                '2020-03-18 03:06:54',
                'Inbound'
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        'values': {
            'data': [
                'Country2 Inbound',
                None,
                'Advanced Mode',
                None,
                'KitchensInc-Main',
                None,
                'Running',
                '2020-03-18 03:06:54',
                'Inbound'
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        'values': {
            'data': [
                'Country3 Inbound',
                None,
                'Advanced Mode',
                None,
                'KitchensInc-Main',
                None,
                'Running',
                '2020-03-18 03:06:55',
                'Inbound'
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        'values': {
            'data': [
                'Billing-Service-English',
                None,
                'Advanced Mode',
                None,
                'KitchensInc-Main',
                None,
                'Running',
                '2020-03-18 03:06:55',
                'Inbound'
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        'values': {
            'data': [
                'testoutbound',
                None,
                None,
                '3',
                None,
                '50',
                'Not Running',
                '2020-03-18 03:06:44',
                'Outbound'
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        'values': {
            'data': [
                'TestOnly',
                None,
                'Basic Mode',
                None,
                None,
                None,
                'Running',
                '2020-04-20 07:22:30',
                'Inbound'
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        'values': {
            'data': [
                'Support-Service-Escalations-English',
                None,
                'Advanced Mode',
                None,
                'KitchensInc-Main',
                None,
                'Running',
                '2020-03-18 03:06:56',
                'Inbound'
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        'values': {
            'data': [
                'ServiceSupportTier2-English',
                None,
                'Advanced Mode',
                None,
                'KitchensInc-Main',
                None,
                'Running',
                '2020-03-18 03:06:56',
                'Inbound'
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        'values': {
            'data': [
                'ServiceSupportTier2-Spanish',
                None,
                'Advanced Mode',
                None,
                'KitchensInc-Main',
                None,
                'Running',
                '2020-03-18 03:06:57',
                'Inbound'
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        'values': {
            'data': [
                'Survey-English-Internal',
                None,
                'Advanced Mode',
                None,
                'KitchensInc-Main',
                None,
                'Running',
                '2020-04-01 17:49:10',
                'Inbound'
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        'values': {
            'data': [
                'Survey 19 Inbound',
                None,
                'Advanced Mode',
                None,
                'KitchensInc-Main',
                None,
                'Running',
                '2020-04-01 17:18:27',
                'Inbound'
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        'values': {
            'data': [
                'Billing-Service-Spanish',
                None,
                'Advanced Mode',
                None,
                'KitchensInc-Main',
                None,
                'Running',
                '2020-03-18 03:06:48',
                'Inbound'
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        'values': {
            'data': [
                'Survey-Spanish-Internal',
                None,
                'Advanced Mode',
                None,
                'KitchensInc-Main',
                None,
                'Running',
                '2020-04-01 17:50:07',
                'Inbound'
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        'values': {
            'data': [
                'Survey-French-Internal',
                None,
                'Advanced Mode',
                None,
                'KitchensInc-Main',
                None,
                'Running',
                '2020-04-01 17:50:37',
                'Inbound'
            ]
        }
    }
],
'timestamp': 1589727753033,
'type': 'CampaignState'
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Struggled big time over this with a similar problem. WARNING that this is not the most efficient or elegant method, but it got the job done for me.

First try using the zeep helper function (https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/helpers.html) to serialize the object to native python. The output will be an Ordered Dictionary. So using your sample response/example above:

`data = zeep.helpers.serialize_object(sample)`

From there you can fetch all the values and turn them into a dataframe by:

`df = pd.DataFrame([d["values"] for d in data["rows"]])`

And then from there you can just manually add the column headers by:

`df.columns=["Campaign Name","Current Action","Mode",...]`